# SQL Server Trigger: INSERTED and DELETED does not exist. What is it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I need to debug (aka reverse engineer) a SQL Server trigger. The trigger is an `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` trigger.

At the beginning of the trigger, there is the following `IF` clause:

```
if not exists(select 1 from inserted) and not exists(select 1 from deleted)
begin
    print 'something'
    return
end
```

The code runs into this `IF` and the text `something` is printed. I wonder, why this happens? I execute an `UPDATE` on the respective table which triggers the trigger. The `IF` basically becomes *true*, when it is NOT an insert and NOT a delete. Hence, I wonder why the `print` statement is executed, because an `UPDATE` essentially is a `DELETE`+`INSERT`.

Comment: I think you mean to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger? That does hold the `inserted` and `deleted` tables. `AFTER INSERT` only holds the `inserted` table IMO.

Comment: `update t set a=b where 1=0`

Comment: And there is a change that 'something' is actually printed out from some other place.

Comment: @NickyvV that is just plain wrong. An AFTER trigger (for an update) will have both deleted and inserted.

Comment: @SeanLange Oh, I only read insert, my bad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition will be true only when no rows were modified by the `UPDATE` statement.